# Differences between "Pay attention to" and "Keep an eye on"

Tags: differences, idioms

What is the difference in meaning between "Pay attention to" and "Keep an eye on"? Can I use both in the same way? Or is one of them stronger than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Paying attention" implies active monitoring.  "Keeping an eye on" is a more passive, possibly intermittent form or attention.

Answer (score 1):

By pure logic it looks to me that we can use the phrase “Pay attention” when we talk about ones mind or thought in order to be more concentrated on what we talk about or what is happening or if we want to emphasize something,  while “Keeping an eye on”  may refer to our focus on a specific material object or a person in order to notice if something happens or changes, etc.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Great help! Unfortunately, I cannot click the "right answer" button anymore (because I asked the question without signing in)! So, appreciate your answer, too!